# $(...).DataTable is not a function using JQ 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, datatable

hello guys i need some help, im trying to load datatable in my website but its kinda not support, im trying change some of my jquery but its make my other function not working then i try to find jq 1.10.2 support for the datatable but its wont load and send error this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/css/home_admin.css">
  <!--css custom-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/home_admin.css"> -->
  <!--jqueryui  -> year slider -->
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- DATATABLE CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row px-3">
      <div class="col-12 card card-menu">
        <div class="card-body">
          <span style="color:white">test</span>
          <div class="col-12">
            <h2>title</h2><br>
            <table id="table_id" class="display nowrap stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">...</th>
                  <th scope="col">....</th>
                  <th scope="col">.....r</th>
                  <th scope="col">.....</th>
                  <th scope="col">......</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td scope="row">1</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td scope="row">2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                  <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <span style="color:white">test</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--JQUERY-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!-- INI SELECTOR  -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- bootsrap-->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- DATATABEL -->
  <script src = "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer >
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <!--js custom-->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/js/diklat.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/js/select-dropdown.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

and the error log is

```
jquery.js:3827 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (name:287)
    at mightThrow (VM21270 jquery.js:3534)
    at process (VM21270 jquery.js:3602)
```

Comment: I tried running your code but I don't get the same error and it loads correctly

Comment: sorry i forget the datatable script : 
      $('#table_id').DataTable();

Comment: i try the code in .html its working but when in .php it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loading all Script files in head section. So all jquery files will get loaded before your body.